# What is a momentary SPST Push Button Switch?

Tags: switches, button

I want to buy a switch (push button) where you press it to break the circuit and then press again to connect the circuit.

I believe that [this is what I'm looking for](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/3-Pcs-x-2-Pin-SPST-OFF-ON-N-O-NO-Red-Round-Cap-Momentary-Push-Button-Switch-/300817253222?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item460a1b0366&_uhb=1#ht_2065wt_1141):

[image]

However, I'm not entirely sure.  I only want to use this for a basic circuit, and I mean really basic, so don't worry about anything there.

Comment: Single Pole (SP) single Throw (ST) is s asimple switch.. When it is momentary, one usually chooses a switch that is Normally Open (NO). Then there DT types where one side is NO and the other NC (normally Closed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SPST NO (Normally Open) Momentary switch is exactly what is inside a computer keyboard - press for on, let go for off.

It sounds like you are looking for a Latching switch (works like a ballpoint pen) instead of Momentary.

If you can only find one with more poles or features (DPDT) it'll do the job - just ignore the extra features.

A brief look shows [this](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Red-Sign-OFF-ON-N-O-Latching-Red-Square-Push-Button-Switch-2-Pin-SPST-/300811352684?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item4609c0fa6c) from the same seller, I suspect he has others...

Comment: Hi again, I purchased this:
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/181022376561?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649#ht_1957wt_1141

and the switches arrived but they are the keyboard style switches :(


is this a misteak by the seller?
becuase the item page says it is a latching switch..
i want to know wether i should dispute this with the seller or not.  

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would let the seller know the switch is not as described. Refer to this thread if need be. Give the seller a chance to fix the problem. But I would have expected you could find electronic parts closer than Hong Kong! The name Dick Smith comes to mind (and I've never been to .au! :-)